# Oracle Apex Client side condition using an item that is set by dynamic action not working

Tags: oracle-apex, client-side

While changing item1, item2 is set up with some value  in dynamic action.

I have another true action to open dialog region. So I'm using client side condition based on item2 when not null.

dialog region not opening even though I can see item2 value as not null in session.

I gave js expression as apex.item('P2_QA').getValue() !='' in client side condition

Answer (score 0):

You're possibly better off using the dedication function for null check, as this covers all item types.

```
!apex.item( "P2_QA" ).isEmpty()
```

How are you setting item 2? Perhaps the onChange event is not triggering, which can depend on how you're setting it.

Try set it manually, and see if it fires.

```
$s('P2_QA','hello');
```

Do this in debug mode, or in the same browser as your builder. Open the browser console and you can see if the event fires.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried to set value manually. But still it is not firing.

Comment: But when I used set type as static and gave 1, then the event is firing